# visual studio code debug adapter wrong symbol on hover over

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

is there a way to control what symbol is passed to evaluate when you hover over something when running a debugadapter ?

the language I'm working with expects the trailing operator, as it uses them to denote a type.

so

string$ is different from string

right now evaluate only gets the "string" part not the "string$"

(I have the response.body.supportsEvaluateForHovers = true; for initialize.

I know for the normal language extension, I can provide my own hoverprovider where I can do my own parsing from the position in the file.

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into that limitation myself. Unfortunately, I this is currently not possible - VSCode [appears to use a hardcoded regex](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/677049d173abd627f35b114d9b93923d6522d905/src/vs/workbench/contrib/debug/common/debugUtils.ts#L60) to extract word ranges for debug hover. There's a few issues related to this:

- [Debug hover does not use AST (#24520)](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/24520)
- [Debug hover does not respect [] when looking for the exact hover range (#51433)](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/51433)
- [Debug hover respect editor.wordSeparators setting (#78073)](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/78073)

Comment: thanks. I added a comment to 24520. either source location info in evaluate, or a IDebugHoverProvider similar to the normal IHoverProvider would be a nice fix for this.